# style.display not working in Vue JS swatch project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am finishing a gradient swatch project an on to the last bit of republish function. I have two name forms one is used on the main creation of the swatch on keypress, and want to use the other one for the edit function, run via a button, but the name is still collected on enter aswwell. I am trying to hide the first form (to be totally not used) and display the second to be used instead.
The form looks like this:

```
 <b-form-input
        id="name"
        size="lg"
        type="text"
        class="search-bar-2"
        placeholder="Name Your Swatch, Enter Hit the Save Edit Button"
        v-model="value3"
        @keypress="republishSwatch"
        >
</b-form-input>
```

and the republishSwatch method is also set as click function in the save button. But here I am just wanting to show the form, current code not working, it doesn't seem to be getting the class of the element "search-box-2". Code is to show the edit button, which works, and hide/show the alternative forms, first form is same as above with class search-box-1. I can give them a different id because need that for the name.

```
   let oldForm = document.querySelector('.search-box-1');
   let newForm = document.querySelector('.search-box-2');
   let saveEditBtn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
   saveEditBtn.style.display = 'block';
   oldForm.style.display = 'none';
   newForm.style.display = 'block';
```

In css the second form is hidden with "display: none!important"  have to use important or it wont hide. Its Bootstrap Vue, If I can get it working though ill probably just collect the name in one function and run that in the republish function via the button.

Any tips welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on [v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) or [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) for conditional rendering.

You can set a variable inside your `data` to `true` and use that for showing/hiding fields.

```
<b-form-input
        id="name"
        size="lg"
        type="text"
        class="search-bar-2"
        placeholder="Name Your Swatch, Enter Hit the Save Edit Button"
        v-model="value3"
        @keypress="republishSwatch"
        v-show="shouldShow"
        >
</b-form-input>
```

Set `shouldShow` from inside a listener on your button.

There are very few cases in which you should manipulate the DOM directly.

Comment: Ok so how to use v-if for ample to display the first form as default (its search-bar-1), and the second form when a swatch is reedited, have got an editSwatch function which shows the button and sends the gradient back to the main  div for editing, but then need the forms swapping? Thanks

Comment: use the negated condition for the other form v-show="!shouldShow"

Comment: OK great, and the other form run the other function, Thanks